# Get Game Center username of already logged in player

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center

I am using Unity's Social class to access Game Center functionality. I only want to get the username of a player who is already logged into Game Center. If the player is not logged in I do not want to bother him with a login.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot access the user name without calling Authenticate. If I call authenticate on a device where the player is NOT logged in, it automatically pops up the login dialog.

Is there any way to avoid the Game Center Login popup?
OR 
Is there any way to access Game Center user info without calling Authenticate?